Generating a truly random sample in ECL
What are some approaches that one could take to generate a truly random sample in ECL? I would like to randomly select 500K records from a 10M input file that is been sprayed to a given Thor cluster.
inputLayout := RECORD
     field1;
     field2;
     ...
END;

inputData := DATASET('~inputFileName.csv', inputLayout, CSV(HEADING(SINGLE), QUOTE('"'));
distOutData := DISTRIBUTE(inputData, RANDOM())[1..500000];

OUTPUT(distOutData,, '~outputFileName.csv', CSV(HEADING(SINGLE), QUOTE('"'))); 

